# DES - Permutation of bits and inverse

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, des

I am currently trying to make an implementation of the encryption scheme DES but I've run into a problem early on. This is the first time I have ever performed bitwise manipulations in a program and I am not very proficient with C either. I apply a permutation and its inverse and the result is not the same as the input.

What I am trying to do is to apply the initial permutation and inverse permutation on a block of 64 bits. I have my block of 64 bits that I want to encrypt in the array input. According to the permutation table IP I take the first bit in the first byte and put it as bit 58 in the permutation. Bit 2 is sent to bit 50 and so on. After the permutation the result is divided in half and the sides swapped. This will enable it to be put back using the same algorithm but with the IPinverse table.

```
include <stdio.h>
include <stdlib.h>

static unsigned char Positions[8] = {1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128};

int main()
{
  unsigned char input[8] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'};
  unsigned char permutation[8];
  unsigned char inverse[8];
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        permutation[i] = 0;
        inverse[i] = 0;
  }

  int IP[8][8] ={{58,50,42,34,26,18,10,2},
                          {60,52,44,36,28,20,12,4},
                          {62,54,46,38,30,22,14,6},
                          {64,56,48,40,32,24,16,8},
                          {57,49,41,33,25,17, 9, 1},
                          {59,51,43,35,27,19,11,3},
                          {61,53,45,37,29,21,13,5},
                          {63,55,47,39,31,23,15,7}};

  int IPinverse[8][8] ={{40,8,48,16,56,24,64,32},
                                      {39,7,47,15,55,23,63,31},
                                      {38,6,46,14,54,22,62,30},
                                      {37,5,45,13,53,21,61,29},
                                      {36,4,44,12,52,20,60,28},
                                      {35,3,43,11,51,19,59,27},
                                      {34,2,42,10,50,18,58,26},
                                      {33, 1,41, 9,49,17,57,25}};

  printf("\n Before: \n");
  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        printf(" %c", input[i]);
  }

  // Initial permutation
  int bit, newpos;
  unsigned char desiredbit;
  for (bit = 0; bit < 64; bit++) {
        // Get the location for where the bit will be sent and translate it to array index
        newpos = ((int)IP[bit/8][bit%8])-1;
        // examine the bit we're currently considering
        desiredbit = input[bit/8] & Positions[bit%8];
        // if equal to zero that means no change necessary
        if (desiredbit != 0) {
              // else it was a 1 and we need to set the appropriate bit to 1
              desiredbit = Positions[newpos%8];
              permutation[newpos/8] = desiredbit ^ permutation[newpos/8];
        }
  }

  printf("\n Permutation: \n");
  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        printf(" %c", permutation[i]);
  }

  // Perform swap
  unsigned char tempcopy[4] = {0,0,0,0};
  int j;
  for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        tempcopy[j] = permutation[j+4];
  }
  for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        permutation[j+4] = permutation[j];
        permutation[j] = tempcopy[j];
  }

  // Reverse Permutation, remember to swap left side with right
  for (bit = 0; bit < 64; bit++) {
        newpos = ((int)IPinverse[bit/8][bit%8])-1;
        desiredbit = permutation[bit/8] & Positions[bit%8];
        if (desiredbit != 0) {
              desiredbit = Positions[newpos%8];
              inverse[newpos/8] = desiredbit ^ inverse[newpos/8];
        }
  }

 printf("\n Reverse Permutation: \n");
  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        printf(" %c", inverse[i]);
  }

  return 0;
```

}

Comment: What does it do right? Where does it start to fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. <strike>Your permutation contains indexes from 1 to 64, but the way you use them, they should be 0 to 63.</strike>
2. What's the swap for? If you permute, swap, then permute back, you won't reach the same place.
3. <strike>You need to verify that the permutation and reverse are indeed opposites. I'm surely not going to go over all the numbers and verify it.</strike>

Comment: 1.The indexes are you can see are all subtracted by 1, thus turning them into 0-63. 2. The swap turned out to be the bug. It should be used for the final permutation when 16 rounds of encryption has been applied on the initial permutation. Removing the swap fixed the problem. 3. The tables are correct. They are exact copies of the tables used in DES encryption. [link]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DES_supplementary_material#Final_permutation_.28IP-1.29